# how can i avoid duplicate emails using mongodb atlas

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

i use mongodb atlas but it keeps duplicating emails, it works fine on mongocompass when using localhost

this is my schema

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  email: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,

    required: true
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I just terminated the cluster and it started working